# "As gentes" é o plural de "a gente". Qual a diferença entre as duas palavras?

Tags: número-gramatical

Em seu poema **"Consoada"**, conhecido por muitos como "A Indesejada das Gentes", Manuel Bandeira usa o substantivo no plural, como se fosse contável.

Quando a Indesejada das **gentes** chegar
(Não sei se dura ou caroável),
talvez eu tenha medo.
Talvez sorria, ou diga:
— Alô, iniludível!
O meu dia foi bom, pode a noite descer.
(A noite com os seus sortilégios.)
Encontrará lavrado o campo, a casa limpa,
A mesa posta,
Com cada coisa em seu lugar.

---

Manuel Bandeira   -   BANDEIRA, M., Libertinagem, 1930

Com a "indesejada das gentes" o autor refere-se, aparentemente, à morte. Neste caso "as gentes" parece ser o plural de "a gente", uma outra forma de referir-se ao povo, às pessoas coletivamente. Teria um outro significado diferente deste? É linguagem antiga que não se usa mais? Ou trata-se apenas de licença poética?

Comment: You never seem to like my answers. And others say nothing either. Go figure...

Answer (score 3):

Priberam: gentes

**nome feminino plural
10. *Povos, nações* (ex.: o direito das gentes é o direito internacional).**

"gente", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2023,
[gentes](https://dicionario.priberam.org/gente.)

Priberam gente:

gente
(
gen·te
)

nome feminino

1. Conjunto indeterminado de pessoas.
2. Conjunto dos habitantes de um território, país. = POPULAÇÃO, POVO
3. Género humano. = HUMANIDADE
4. Alguma ou algumas pessoas (ex.: ainda há gente na rua a esta hora). ≠ NINGUÉM
5. Grupo de pessoas com afinidades ou interesses comuns.
6. Grupo de homens armados. = BANDO
7. Índole das pessoas.
8. Ser humano. = PESSOA
9. Os membros de uma família.

"gente.", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2023, https://dicionario.priberam.org/gente..

Comment: Lambie, Ao contrário do que você escreveu, e apagou logo após, considero suas respostas sempre valiosas. Só que eu esperava (e ainda espero) uma resposta completa.  Minha pergunta inclui: 1. Especificamente no poema "A Indesejada das Gentes", qual o significado de "gentes" (não é necessário citar todos os significados possíveis da palavra.  2. É uma palavra antiga que caiu em desuso?   3. Trata-se simplesmente de licença poética?

Comment: @Centaurus Acho óbvio que no poema é povos. Os poetas sempre usam palavras um pouco fora do comun.

Comment: Parece-me mais provável que signifique "ser humano".

Comment: A indesejada das gentes quer dizer ser humano??

Comment: Não, "gentes" quer dizer ser humano.  A indesejada das gentes, ou melhor, a indesejada do ser humano é a morte.  Manuel Bandeira faz uso de um eufemismo.

Comment: A Indesejada das gentes pode ser simplesmente a morte, né? A morte é o que a humanidade não deseja.